# Gatsby: Installed a new theme, deleted it, now my app is broke

Tags: reactjs, graphql, themes, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby and built a basic app with a starter theme. After getting the theme up and running I decided to install a new theme. I couldn't get the theme to work and uninstalled it, but now I'm getting the error:

```
There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Cannot query field "themeUiConfig" on type "Query".

If you don't expect "themeUiConfig" to exist on the type "Query" it is most likely a typo.
However, if you expect "themeUiConfig" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:

- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server
- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have
- You want to optionally use your field "themeUiConfig" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")

It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "Query":
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions

File: /Users/nick/Desktop/ui-website-sandbox/gatsby_crash_course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/src/hooks/configOptions.js
```

Restarted the server multiple times and it doesn't fix this. How can I fix this?

Comment: git - revert to previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling your theme likely removed the `themeUiConfig` piece of data, or your app's connection to it.

Find that graphQL query that is erroring, and remove or re-connect that request.

Alternatively, it could be that your new theme expected some data, so make sure you have run through the steps for uninstalling it correctly. Or if you are using source-control like Git, you can search online for a way to `revert` your commits and undo your code back to a time when it worked.

Comment: I'm brand new to Gatsby and GraphQL. I have no idea how to do that. I don't see any queries in my app that query for `themeUiConfig`

Comment: `rm -rf .cache && gatsby develop`